# Rails / Activeadmin : How to add/edit seconds to a data with datatype :time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a variable "time_to_succeed" which represents the time for a team to succeed in a mission. This variable will be added/edited in activeadmin. I need minutes and seconds as the game duration is under an hour. Problem is, activeadmin allows me to add/edit only hours and minutes of this variable. Adding ", :as => :time_picker" did not solve my issue.

Maybe the datatype is not correct but I could not find one more suitable than time.

A bit of code might be helpful :

```
 class PurchaseOrder < ActiveRecord::Base       
  scope :today, -> { where("booking_date >= ?", Date.today).where("booking_date < ?", Date.tomorrow) }
  scope :tomorrow, -> { where("booking_date >= ?", Date.tomorrow).where("booking_date < ?", Date.tomorrow+1) }

  before_save :default_values
  def default_values
    self.price_ttc = self.paid_by_card.to_f + self.paid_in_cash.to_f + self.paid_by_check.to_f
    self.price_ht = self.price_ttc / 1.2
  end

  has_attached_file :team_picture, styles: { small: "64x64>", medium: "150x150>", large: "300x300>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :team_picture, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"]

  just_define_datetime_picker :booking_date
end


ActiveAdmin.register PurchaseOrder do

  permit_params :first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone, :booking_date,
                :time_to_succeed, :number_of_players, :team_name, :paid_by_card, :paid_in_cash, :paid_by_check, :level, :status, :team_picture,
                :booking_date_date, :booking_date_time_hour, :booking_date_time_minute, :scenario_id

  scope :today
  scope :tomorrow
  scope :all

  index do
    column "Prénom", :first_name
    column "Nom", :last_name
    column :email
    column "Réservation", :booking_date
    column :number_of_players
    column :time_to_succeed
    actions
  end  

  show do
    h3 purchase_order.last_name
    attributes_table do
      row :first_name
      row :last_name
      row :email
      row :phone      
      row :booking_date
      row :scenario_id
      row :time_to_succeed
      row :number_of_players
      row :price_ttc
      row :price_ht
      row :status
      row :created_at
      row :paid_by_card
      row :paid_in_cash
      row :paid_by_check
      row :level
      row :team_name
      row :team_picture do
        image_tag purchase_order.team_picture.url(:medium)
      end
    end
    active_admin_comments
  end

  form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|
    f.inputs "Details" do
      f.input :first_name
      f.input :last_name
      f.input :email
      f.input :phone      
      f.input :booking_date, :as => :just_datetime_picker          
      f.input :scenario_id, :label => 'Scenario', :as => :select, :collection => Scenario.all.map{|u| ["#{u.name}", u.id]}
      f.input :time_to_succeed, :as => :time_picker
      f.input :number_of_players
      f.input :status      
      f.input :paid_by_card
      f.input :paid_in_cash
      f.input :paid_by_check
      f.input :level, :label => 'Niveau', :as => :select, :collection => ["détente", "expert"]
      f.input :team_name
      f.input :team_picture, :as => :file, :hint => f.object.team_picture.present? \
        ? image_tag(f.object.team_picture.url(:small))
        : content_tag(:span, "no image")
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

Couldn't find anything on Google. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks